# How can I get an OpenMP program to use multiple cores on macOS

Tags: macos, parallel-processing, openmp

I have an application which uses a third party library which relies on OpenMP for performance.

I have successfully built the app on macOS and have tested it and found that it runs correctly in the sense that if I set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` the correct number of threads are run (as reported by `Activity Monitor` and some diagnostic output statements.

The problem is that it seems to execute these threads on a single core and I want each thread on a separate core; my processing is CPU intensive and I will gain little to nothing from context switching on a single core.

The OpenMP documentation suggests using `KMP_AFFINITY` for this but explicitly says that this is not supported on OS X.

Is there any way to force the distribution of OpenMP threads over multiple cores?

PS I am aware that I could use GCD and a host of other solutions to try to solve this but I'm using a third party cross platform library so these options are not viable for me.

**EDIT**

After further reading I've managed to extract more info using `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV` and `OMP_DISPLAY_AFFINITY` as shown below.

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 OMP_PLACES=cores OMP_PROC_BIND=spread  OMP_DISPLAY_AFFINITY=true OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=true  ../bin/my_app

OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT BEGIN
   _OPENMP='201611'
  [host] OMP_AFFINITY_FORMAT='OMP: pid %P tid %i thread %n bound to OS proc set {%A}'
  [host] OMP_ALLOCATOR='omp_default_mem_alloc'
  [host] OMP_CANCELLATION='FALSE'
  [host] OMP_DEFAULT_DEVICE='0'
  [host] OMP_DISPLAY_AFFINITY='TRUE'
  [host] OMP_DISPLAY_ENV='TRUE'
  [host] OMP_DYNAMIC='FALSE'
  [host] OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS='1'
  [host] OMP_MAX_TASK_PRIORITY='0'
  [host] OMP_NESTED: deprecated; max-active-levels-var=1
  [host] OMP_NUM_THREADS='4'
  [host] OMP_PROC_BIND='spread'
  [host] OMP_SCHEDULE='static'
  [host] OMP_STACKSIZE='8M'
  [host] OMP_TARGET_OFFLOAD=DEFAULT
  [host] OMP_THREAD_LIMIT='2147483647'
  [host] OMP_TOOL='enabled'
  [host] OMP_TOOL_LIBRARIES: value is not defined
  [host] OMP_WAIT_POLICY='PASSIVE'
OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT END


OMP: pid 6686 tid 2795865 thread 0 bound to OS proc set {undefined}
OMP: pid 6686 tid 2795867 thread 1 bound to OS proc set {undefined}
OMP: pid 6686 tid 2795868 thread 2 bound to OS proc set {undefined}
OMP: pid 6686 tid 2795869 thread 3 bound to OS proc set {undefined}
```

I've experimented setting `OMP_PLACES` to `cores`, `threads` and `sockets` but the affinity always shows `undefined`. Could this be part of the problem? Do I need to specify places somehow?

Comment: This sounds a lot like if the code that invoked the parallel section pinned _itself_ to a single core. Spawned threads inherit the affinities of their “parent” thread. Are you playing with CPU sets in your own code?

Comment: Have you tried to cross-check the above described behaviour by running the same code on any other ( non-OS-X ) system - a non-emulated, non-virtualised, native { x86-linux | ARM-linux | win? } for which you have the said cross-platform library, so out of question a doable step, to confirm or deny the said hypothesis?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I'm not consciously doing any concurrency work at al in my code.  The library in question is https://github.com/gadomski/fgt and is invoked from https://github.com/gadomski/cpd. My code simply loads appropriate data sets and invokes the CPD code to compute correspondences.

Comment: @user3666197 This is a sensible suggestion but will take a bit of effort to implement . I had hoped I was missing something simple